# CONST is pretty much useless in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I've read what I could find on this issue, but I'm pretty much baffled at the lack of alternatives. If you have an OOP project in PHP, using consts is as ugly as it can get. Here's the problem:

```
class Invisible {
   CONST youCantSeeMe = "";
}

class Ugly {
    $invisible;
    static $invisible2;

    function __construct() {
       $this->$invisible = new Invisible();
       self::$invisible2 = New Invisible();

       $this->invisible::youCantSeeMe; (illegal, crashes project)
       self::$invisible2::youCantSeeMe; (illegal, crashes project)
    }

   function uglyFunction() {
      //this is the only, ugly way to do it
      $invisible = $this->invisible;
      $invisible::youCantSeeMe (this works)
   }
}
```

The only other way I've found around it, is to make a public get for each const you have (cumbersome, waste of time), or with a magic __get using a reflection class (expensive).

There HAS to be a better way than these options?

Comment: I was reading that a few minutes ago actually, I don't see how that clarifies anything

Comment: You are right about the bug with not initializing the const, however, you failed to understand the question here given your answer. What I (and people from other threads) are looking to do, IS access it using an instance of the object

Comment: Surprisingly, the things that most affect me to make a clean project have been the things I can't get an answer or that there are no answers online, or where the thread died before anyone reached a definitive conclusion or a good solution. This is one of these cases

Comment: Can someone confirm to me that PHP messed up with this, and there is no elegant way to use conts and we just have to mess our projects to deal with it?

Comment: unfortunately that threw an error too Rob, it's an illegal statement (syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM))

Answer (score 1):

I believe your complaint really has to do with [incomplete dereferencing support](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax#incomplete_dereferencing_support).

> `::` only accepts simple reference variables on the left hand side

This is fixed in the [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) which is implemented in PHP 7.

Comment: thank you very much Paul, really nice to see we might be getting this on PHP 7. I will prepare my project now so I can update it the most straightforward way when it's out. This was an answer I was hoping for, this is a solution to this. Really appreciate it